# AngularJS - Clone element with functionality

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive in which I want to clone a DOM element that they are exactly the same with all bindings. That when one of them changes, the other one changes as well. Is that possible? I understand I somehow have to compile the copied element but are they interconnected with the changes then?

```
angular.module('app').directive('test', function ($compile) {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

   angular.element(document).ready(function () {

      var $header = angular.element(XXX).clone();
      // $compile($header)(scope); // not sure about this one. it doesn't work
      var $newHeader = angular.element(YYY).append($header);

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example on how to achieve this.

This example use a controller with a `displayContent` method that display content of an element on click.

We search inside the `div` element with `test` directive the existing `<p>` element with `ng-click` directive, clone it, change its content and append it to our div parent element.

Before appending this element copy, it needs to be compiled so that Angular will recognize its bindings.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleController as ctrl">     
    <div test>
        <p ng-click="ctrl.displayContent($event)">Dummy</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.displayContent = function($event) {
        alert($event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    }     

});

angular.module('app').directive('test', function ($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           // Find <p> element inside our elment with `test` directive
           var pElement = element.find('p');
           // Clone <p>
           var pElementCopy = pElement.clone();
           // Change its content
           pElementCopy.html("Foo");
           // In order ng-click to work on this copy, you must compile it
           // If you remove the following line, then ng-click won't work
           $compile(pElementCopy)(scope);

           element.append(pElementCopy)
      }
    }
});
```

Link to the plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/T4elaGJMgMtxX6bKJHf0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need an extra controller for this? When I only use have the directive I get a JS error with the $compile function:
TypeError: Cannot read property '$render' of undefined

Comment: No the `SampleController` is only here for demo purposes. You can remove it and replace child `p` tag with `<p another-directive>Dummy</div>`. ` another-directive` could be a directive which for example display a tooltip.